# Add another string to complete existing strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that look like

```
Category
A
C
E
J
AA
AB
AE
AK
AO
F
L
O
AW
AQ
```

The correct data should have two letters, such as AA, AB, and AK. However, some entries only have the second alphabet.

The final result would be:

```
Category
AA
AC
AE
AJ
AA
AB
AE
AK
AO
AF
AL
AO
AW
AQ
```

I know how we can add a string "A" to all entries in this column. However, is it possible to only add "A" to entries with one letter?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What is your data stored in? A `pd.Series`?

Comment: Ah it's a column in dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.pad`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html):

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].str.pad(2, side='left', fillchar='A')
```

[out]

```
   Category
0        AA
1        AC
2        AE
3        AJ
4        AA
5        AB
6        AE
7        AK
8        AO
9        AF
10       AL
11       AO
12       AW
13       AQ
```

Comment: the best solution.

Comment: This is magical!! Thank you so much @Chris A for the help!! Never thought there would be a function like this!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`df['Category'] = df['Category'].apply(lambda x: 'A' + x if len(x) < 2 else x)`